# How to change button colour back to original when clicked again

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to change the button colour to black when clicked then change it back to white when clicked again. I'm trying to make Game Of Life for a school project.

I tried if statements but it doesn't change back to white, maybe I missed something simple. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI(Frame):
   def __init__(self, master=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.title("Window") #Window title
        self.pack()

        master.geometry("1280x720") #Window size

        self.button={}#Dictionary for buttons

        self.create_button()

    def create_button(self):
        indexList =[i for i in range(1000)]
        self._button = Button(self, bg='white')
        print(self._button.cget('bg'))

        xPos = 0
        yPos = 0
        for index in indexList:
            if(yPos == 40):
                xPos = xPos + 20
                yPos = 0
            if(xPos == 10):
                yPos = 8

            self._button = Button(self, height=2, width=4, command = lambda 
            i = index: self.changecolour(i))
            self.button[index] = self._button
            self._button.grid(row=xPos, column =yPos)
            yPos = yPos + 1


    def changecolour(self,index):
        aList = []

        for i in range(1000):
            aList.append([i,0])

        for i in aList:
            if index == i[0]:
                if 0 == i[1]: 
                    self.button[index].configure(bg = 'black')
                    i[1] = 1
                else:
                    self.button[index].configure(bg = 'white')
                    i[1] = 0

root = Tk()
game_gui = GUI(master=root)
game_gui.mainloop()
```

As you can see it changes the button colour to black and it should change it back to white when clicked again, but it seems to just ignore the if statement.

Comment: You are not breaking the loop of `aList` so the if-statement is hit multiple times.

Comment: And it's nonsense to hardcode `i[0]` or `i[i]` inside a loop. What are you actually doing?

Comment: I tried to add a value next to the "index" of the button as i have multiple of those. Then when the colour changes so does the i[1] value. I'm sure there is a better way to do this but this is what came to my head when i was doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the problem:

`aList` is not a global list

`aList` is created in `changecolour()` as a local list each time the subroutine is run

this means that when you do `i[1] = 1` or `i[1] = 0` it only changes the local list-  `aList`. When the subroutine is run again, a new `aList` is created as a new local list.

to solve the problem define `aList` in the main program and make it a global list:

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI(Frame):
   def __init__(self, master=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.title("Window") #Window title
        self.pack()

        master.geometry("1280x720") #Window size

        self.button={}#Dictionary for buttons

        self.create_button()

    def create_button(self):
        indexList =[i for i in range(1000)]
        self._button = Button(self, bg='white')
        print(self._button.cget('bg'))

        xPos = 0
        yPos = 0
        for index in indexList:
            if(yPos == 40):
                xPos = xPos + 20
                yPos = 0
            if(xPos == 10):
                yPos = 8

            self._button = Button(self, height=2, width=4, command = lambda 
            i = index: self.changecolour(i))
            self.button[index] = self._button
            self._button.grid(row=xPos, column =yPos)
            yPos = yPos + 1


    def changecolour(self,index):
        #aList IS NO LONGER CREATED HERE

        for i in range(1000):
            aList.append([i,0])

        for i in aList:
            if index == i[0]:
                if 0 == i[1]: 
                    self.button[index].configure(bg = 'black')
                    i[1] = 1
                else:
                    self.button[index].configure(bg = 'white')
                    i[1] = 0

global aList #MAKE IT A GLOBAL LIST
aList = [] #CREATE THE EMPTY aList LIST
root = Tk() 
game_gui = GUI(master=root)
game_gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for that! It worked, but instead of using a global i just made it as a self.aList outside the method as my teacher keeps telling us to avoid globals. Now it works, thank you again for the help!

Comment: great! happy to help!